# Why is Prelude.drop faster than a trivial one?

Tags: haskell, optimization, singly-linked-list

I made some runs of:

```
main = print $ head . drop (2^30) $ [1..]
```

— With both `Prelude.drop` and a trivial `drop`. The Prelude variant is consistently faster by about 45% and I cannot discover why. I even extracted the definition of `GHC.List.drop` from `base-4.11.1.0` but it performs worse than my trivial code! What is going on?

This is what I am doing:

```
% stack ghc -- --version           
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2
```

`Prelude.drop`:

```
% git checkout drop-prelude
% git clean --force
% cat ListTest.hs
module Main where

main = print $ head . drop (2^30) $ [1..]
% stack ghc -- ListTest.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ListTest.hs, ListTest.o )
Linking ListTest ...
% time ./ListTest
1073741825
./ListTest  18.76s user 0.09s system 99% cpu 18.906 total
```

A trivial `drop`:

```
% git checkout drop-naive 
% git clean --force
% cat ListTest.hs
module Main where

dropNaive :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
dropNaive 0 xs = xs
dropNaive n [ ] = [ ]
dropNaive n (x: xs) = dropNaive (pred n) xs

main = print $ head . dropNaive (2^30) $ [1..]
% stack ghc -- ListTest.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( ListTest.hs, ListTest.o )
Linking ListTest ...
% time ./ListTest
1073741825      
./ListTest  31.56s user 0.12s system 99% cpu 31.774 total
```

`drop` from `GHC.List`:

```
% git checkout drop-ghc 
% git clean --force
% cat ListTest.hs 
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

module ListTest where

dropGhc :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
{-# INLINE dropGhc #-}
dropGhc n xs
  | n <= 0     = xs
  | otherwise  = unsafeDrop n xs
  where
    unsafeDrop :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
    unsafeDrop !_ []     = []
    unsafeDrop 1  (_:xs) = xs
    unsafeDrop m  (_:xs) = unsafeDrop (m - 1) xs
% cat ListTestRunner.hs 
import ListTest

main = print $ head . dropGhc (2^30) $ [1..]
% stack ghc -- ListTestRunner.hs
[1 of 2] Compiling ListTest         ( ListTest.hs, ListTest.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( ListTestRunner.hs, ListTestRunner.o )
Linking ListTestRunner ...
% time ./ListTestRunner
1073741825            
./ListTestRunner  35.35s user 0.14s system 99% cpu 35.591 total
```

Comment: Probably has something to do with stream fusion / rewrite rules. Anyway this comparison is somewhat useless because much (most?) of the time will be spent generating the list.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I do not understand. If you are talking about particular compiler optimizations, why are they not triggered anymore when the code is transplanted away from `base`?

Comment: @leftaroundabout I assumed all three variants will spend the same time generating the list, since the code in `main` is identical. Is it wrong to think so?

Comment: Well, it isn't the same code. There's probably a rewrite rule somewhere in `Data.List` that fuses `Prelude.head . Prelude.drop n` into something more efficient, but the compiler can't really know that this could also apply to your `dropGhc`.

Comment: I think the most likely `foldr`/`build` fusion point is between `enumFrom` and `drop`. If those fuse, dropping all those elements is done as a non-allocating loop.  Actually, that seems like a useful test.  If you run your programs with `+RTS -s` do they report noticeably different allocation?

Comment: You can use http://hackage.haskell.org/package/list-fusion-probe to find out where fusion happens.

Comment: Maybe the optimization flags are not the same when you compile your executable and when Prelude was compiled? (like -O2 for example, see https://wiki.haskell.org/Performance/GHC)

Comment: Oh, you are running `ghc` without any optimization flags? Explicitly pass `-O1` or `-O2` when you use the copy from the `Prelude` and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: @leftaroundabout, no, `drop` does not participate in fold/build fusion or, as far as I know, any other rewrite rules in `base`. People have tried to give it rules that don't behave very badly, but they've failed.

Comment: What does the Core say?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have made this mistake before, so I had a suspicion...

It looks like you are just not compiling with optimizations enabled.  The prelude is compiled with optimizations and linked in, so you are implicitly using optimized code when you use the prelude's `drop`.  Reproducing locally (after reducing the constant from `2^30` to `2^25` — there is no reason to make yourself wait so long), enabling optimizations causes `dropGhc` and prelude `drop` to have identical timing, and `dropNaive` is not significantly worse.  There is a slight difference in phrasing between `dropGhc` and `dropNaive` that might have subtle results on the generated code; I don't have a good intuition for why one would be better than the other.

Note also that `base` is a special package in the sense that it is built as part of `ghc`'s build process, using its own build system, rather than by Cabal, as ordinary packages. As @sjakobi pointed out in comments, [there is a setting in `ghc`'s build configuration](https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/b4e64839a95d024252950f07e3da50c3d4087882/mk/config.mk.in#L318) that sets the level of optimization for `base` at `O2`.

Comment: Thank you. But why is Prelude always compiled with optimizations? Where is that specified?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov, probably somewhere in the [ghc source code](https://github.com/ghc/ghc).  The prelude is compiled once into `Prelude.o` (or similar) then linked to your program, thus whatever settings applied when it was first compiled are the ones reflected in its code; it's not like a C header which is "pasted" verbatim into your project.

Comment: I looked at `base.cabal` and nothing along the lines of `ghc-options: -O2` revealed itself.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov [optimization is enabled by default by `cabal`](https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/nix-local-build.html#cfg-field-optimization).  Also, I admire your diligence to really find the root cause!

Comment: Oh weird, [stack apparently uses the same options as cabal](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/2132) so now I can't explain.  You could try `--cabal-verbose` option...

Comment: The optimization level for `base` is specified in GHC's build configurations: https://github.com/ghc/ghc/blob/b4e64839a95d024252950f07e3da50c3d4087882/mk/config.mk.in#L318

Comment: @IgnatInsarov, be sure to see sjakobi's comment. The libraries shipped with GHC are not actually built by `cabal-install`. The GHC build system uses a custom build procedure to allow it to build more things in parallel. In particular, it only looks at what modules depend on what modules--it doesn't care about package dependencies. So if module `A` from package `a` depends on module `B` from package `b`, it will compile `B` before `A`, but may compile `A` in parallel with other modules in `b`.